# Django media files are not being display

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to display the uploaded media files to a user on Django, however, although the GET request returns 200 which means the file exists I still cannot the image being displayed properly below is my configuration for uploading media files.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_DIRS = [ 
             os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

and in my project urls.py I have:

`static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT ) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT`)

On my model the upload path is:

image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_uuid('media/users_images/'), blank=True) which when an image is uploaded I can see that the file is added however, on my page I do not see the file and it shows me a thumbnail.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I display the file using `{{ image.image.url }}`. an image is an object of my model which is called Images`

My model field for storing images is: image = `models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_uuid('media/users_images/'), blank=True)`

My views for handling the upload which I believe it works as images with their uuid are created in the media folder:

```
form = ImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.save(False)
            image.author = request.user
            image.save()
```

inside my template I use:

```
<img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ image.image.url }}"
                    alt="Image shared by {{ image.author.username }}">
```

Also images are being loaded as the GET request returns a status code 200 but I still cannot see my images.

**EDIT 2**

I notice that when I go to the image URL the one that I get from the Network tab on chrome, it redirects me to the main page so:

```
ttp://127.0.0.1:8000/media/media/users_images/943c733e-de1f-40a9-9418-9decf6f9d38c.jpg
```

I get redirected to the main page and it doesn't display the image itself, also on the network tab, it shows the type as `text`  not jpg. I do not know what is causing this issue.

I also do have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set correctly on my upload form element.

Comment: How do you display these files? Can you show some part of the template where you display media files?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsemyes I added it to question

Comment: but you did use `<img src="{{ image.image.url }}">`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsemyes sorry my bad for not saying I set the image src as that

Comment: all seems to be ok. show more code of your template and model. you can try using a different browser or use ctrl + F5

Comment: @RezaGH I have added all the code I do not get what causing the issue here

Comment: i know. that's why i want to see your queryset and model fields

Comment: @RezaGH Okay yes i have added al the fields and methods for retrieving images

Comment: Can you share the view that renders the template?

Comment: I would start to check if {{ image.image.url }} delivers the expected result by just looking on the page source in your browser

Comment: use ctrl + u and see if there is a link in image tag. check it if is.

Comment: your using the picture that user uploaded? have your form included enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: @Razenstein I hav taken a look and when I paste the image url into the browser it redirects me to the main page. I do not know what is causing this issue.